# Recursive function for keys as dirs and values as filname

Tags: php, recursion

I have array with following structure:

```
'common' => [
    'dailyPlan' => [
        '2017-03-14' => 'some_url_14_mar',
        '2017-02-25' => 'some_url_25_feb',
        '2017-01-01' => 'some_url_1_jan',
    ],
    'dailyResults' => [
        '2017-04-19' => 'some_url2',
        '2020-02-22' => 'future_url',
    ],
]
```

As a result I need return array with elements for creating directories:

```
common/dailyPlan/2017-03-14/some_url_14_mar
common/dailyPlan/2017-02-25/some_url_25_feb
...
common/dailyResults/2017-04-19/some_url2
common/dailyResults/2020-02-22/future_url
```

This is a simple example, real data more complex. But main rule: keys - are directories, values - filename. I have some troubles with recursion, help plz ;)

Tried something like this

```
$final = [];

function rec3(&$array, $path = [], &$final) {

    foreach ($array as $k => $v) {

        $path[$k] = $k;
        if (is_array($v)) {
            rec3($v, $path, $final);
        }
        else {
            $path[] = $v;
            $final[] = join('/', $path);
        }
    }
}

rec3($urls, [], $final);
```

Comment: Where is your code and exactly what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: What have tried? For recursion - the first step is to always identify your base case/when to stop. For you, this might be `if (!is_array($val))`.

Comment: It could be infinite depths, so fixed number of foreach is not an option.

Comment: @blackbam thank you for link! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32604503/php-create-breadcrumb-list-of-every-value-in-nested-array